# Cannot get wildcard search working with Sphinx Real Time indexes

Tags: full-text-search, wildcard, sphinx

There are several questions already here on SO for this, as well as on Google. However, repeated attempts and plenty of Googling has not netted me an answer so far. This doesn't seem difficult, but clearly I'm missing something.

I've added combinations of the following:

```
enable_star = 1
dict = keywords
min_infix_len = 3
min_prefix_len = 3
```

Note: I did not do prefix and infix at the same time.

I have blown away and re-created my indexes, re-started searchd and still no luck.

If I insert a value such as "wildcardtest" I can do the following with a hit

> select * from rtindex where match('wildcardtest');

but anything else such as

> select * from rtindex where match('wildcardt*');

returns 0 results.

I was using 2.1.4 but upgraded to 2.1.9 with no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to 2.2.7 and tweaked the config a bit and this is working.

The essential config option needed is dict=keywords

min_prefix_len/min_infix_len also work, but they do seem to change the behavior compared to dict=keywords on its own. Searching for the same pattern with the various config options yields slightly different results.

I did have to re-build my disk-based indexes and then attach (after truncating) to the RT indexes to get the historical content searchable the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the RT indexes, but on a regular index i would pass it in like so '"wildcard*"'. I found that wrapping it like this I would get the results that I was looking for. In your conf file you should also have enable_star = 1 as well.